# Set value for simple_form collection entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following code:

```
<% s.input :style_id, :collection => Style.all.map {|style| "#{style.brand.name} #{style.model.name} #{style.submodel.name} #{style.name}"}.sort %>
```

Basically I need to build the presented entry using the map block above, but need to have the ID assigned to each entry as well, so the params sent to the controller make sense to the controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out:

```
Style.all.map {|style| ["#{style.brand.name} #{style.model.name} #{style.submodel.name} #{style.name}", style.id]}.sort
```